# Selecting Qt5 using qtchooser

Tags: 16.04, qt

The question is, before I try to build supercollider from source, making sure that I am using Qt5. Problem is this:

```
jsimon@edgy:~$ qmake -v
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
jsimon@edgy:~$ locate qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
```

I think is there something misconfigured with qtchooser, docs here:

[Qtchooser man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/qtchooser.1.html)

and here:

[Qtchooser on Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.4/general/qtchooser.html)

More digging, there is a directory with some symlinks in it:

```
jsimon@edgy:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser$ ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    50 Sep  1 06:04 4.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    50 Sep  1 06:04 5.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    50 Sep  1 06:04 qt4.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    50 Sep  1 06:04 qt5.conf -> ../../../share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
```

And another deeper directory with what looks to me like the problem, a symlink giving Qt4 as the default:

```
jsimon@edgy:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser$ ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 Sep  1 06:04 default.conf -> ../../../../share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
```

Some information from qtchooser:

```
jsimon@edgy:~$ qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Looking at this page, it ought to be simple:

[Handling Multiple Qt Versions](http://harishnavnit.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/handling-multiple-versions-of-qt/)

However:

```
jsimon@edgy:~$ export QT_SELECT=qt5
jsimon@edgy:~$ printenv
[snip]
QT_SELECT=qt5
[snip]
jsimon@edgy:~$ qmake -v
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

Back where we're started, no change. Now what?

Comment: Have you read the readme for supercollider located  [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supercollider/supercollider/master/README_LINUX.md). It details several dependencies to install including Qt. It also details how to set the path to Qt when you build (for both a repository install or an install from the Qt website). It shouldn't be necessary to use qtchooser.

Comment: Yes, I've studied that closely, and discussed the issue on the supercollider mailing list. http://new-supercollider-mailing-lists-forums-use-these.2681727.n2.nabble.com/Build-3-7-2-from-source-on-ubuntu-16-04-td7627556.html#a7627596

Comment: It just seemed to me that qtchooser was probably the 'right' way to do this.

Comment: If the primary error is `could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake': No such file or directory`, that would suggest you need to install (or re-install) the `qt5-qmake` package

Comment: Solved! Thanks. I didn't realise that qmake and qt were two different things. Installing qt5-qmake using Synaptic seems to fix everything. Umm, how does this work, is there some way I now mark this question as solved, or answered?

Comment: In my case `qt5-qmake` was already installed, and I still had this problem. My solution was to change the link `sudo ln -s -T /usr/share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf -f
`

Answer (score 7):

All of this turned out to be a red herring: all that was needed was to install qmake, for example:

```
sudo apt install qt5-qmake
```

Comment: Now: wash, rinse, repeat for Qt6. Ha! Surprises on the way!