# PyQT Creator Qt designer: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, qt-creator, pyqt

There is a bash command that comes with installing [PyQT Creator](https://www.qt.io/qt-features-libraries-apis-tools-and-ide/) called `designer` that will run a tool called Qt Designer, found under the Qt Creator package. It helps you create GUIs - pretty cool stuff.

There is a problem though... whenever I run `designer`, I get this error:

```
designer: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer': No such file or directory
```

And that's great - I don't want it to execute `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer`, I want it to execute `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer`, the difference being between "qt4" (first path) and "qt5" (second path). That's where designer is.

I looked around and found this command `type -a (command)` and it would tell you where the command definition is "located", if I understand correctly. So I looked it up and got:

```
$ type -a designer
designer is /usr/bin/designer
```

But I can't edit that file... it's a bunch of gibberish (side question, what does it mean when a file has no file extension? What does that make it?)

So, my question is, how can I get the command `designer` to execute `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer`?

Edit: `which designer` also returns `/usr/bin/designer`,

also:
`$ file /usr/bin/designer
/usr/bin/designer: symbolic link to qtchooser'`

So I also took a look at qtchooser... seems like its a command (not entirely sure what it does).

Here is some output:

```
file /usr/bin/qtchooser 
/usr/bin/qtchooser: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=96215e9441b8361f0cc57b37db70fc50752cb05a, stripped
```

Comment: You can read about the file extension topic here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48019/what-are-the-common-file-extensions-in-ubuntu. In (IIRC all) Linux systems, files don't have a file extension by default.

Comment: `file /usr/bin/designer` to find out what kind of file it is.

Comment: Am I right that the output ot `which designer` is also `/usr/bin/designer`? Please add the output of `file /usr/bin/designer` to your question using the [formatting tools](https://$SITEURL$/help/formatting).

Comment: @dessert made the edits

Comment: OK, so `qtchooser` doesn't know about QT5 and thinks you have QT4 instead – tricky! If it's just for `designer`, I'd just define an alias with `alias designer=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer` in the `~/.bash_aliases` file.

Comment: **Very** related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/820054/selecting-qt5-using-qtchooser. Try `export QT_SELECT=qt5` and if that doesn't help `sudo apt install qt5-qmake`!

Comment: @dessert yeah that's what I did as a workaround. Didn't know qtchooser was the culprit though. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @dessert I tried that just now (the link you posted) and it didnt work :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [@dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert) for helping me out.

I ran `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` and everything worked fine.

The answer was "inspired" from the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820054/selecting-qt5-using-qtchooser), which didn't work for me, but might work for you if you are having the same problem and my solution didnt work.

While this does not directly answer my question... it solves my problem, so yay

Comment: I know  I'm a bit out of time, but I just found [this resource](https://gist.github.com/ujjwal96/1dcd57542bdaf3c9d1b0dd526ccd44ff) which I want to sare. Basically, you can edit `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf` changing the default to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin` and whenever you call `designer` it will launch the qt5 one!